# fs.readDirSync dies when changing directory o.O

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs

Working on a node.js project, I found something interesting.

## Test 1

*Here is my initial directory structure for reference:*

```
├── test
    └── test.js
├── start.js
├── package.json
```

### start.js

```
const fs = require('fs');

console.log(fs.readdirSync("./test"));
```

used `node start.js` to run the script.

### Output

```
['test.js']
```

## Test 2

*I changed my directory structure and tried again:*

```
├── src
    ├── test
        └── test.js
    ├── start.js
├── package.json
```

This time used `node ./src/start.js` to run the script.

### Output

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir './test'.
```

---

Please could someone explain why this happen and why this works:

```
require("./test/test.js");
```

and how I can get around this by only using relative pathing (no other modules or `__dirname`).
I am relatively new to NodeJs.

- OS: Windows
- Node version: 14.15.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `./` in your path you pass to `fs.readdirSync()` is relative to the current working directory, not relative to `__dirname`.

When you start your app with node `./src/start.js`, your current working directory is the parent of `src`.  So, when you then try `fs.readdirSync("./test")`, it's not looking where there's a `test` subdirectory.

> how I can get around this by only using relative pathing (no other modules or __dirname). I am relatively new to NodeJs.

Well, if you want to specify a relative path that is relative to the current module's location, then you HAVE to use `__dirname` to construct a path relative to that because the current working directory is global to your app, is what `fs.readdirSync()` and pretty much every function except `require()` uses to resolve relative paths and is dependent upon what the system working directory was when your app was started.

Module-relative paths are constructed using `__dirname`.  That's how you do it in nodejs.

---

`require()` has it's own set of rules (which you can see [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together)) and those rules have nothing at all to do with `fs.readdirSync()` or other library functions which use the current working directory.

The rules for `require()` have all sorts of things in them that are specific to module loading (such as defaulting to look in the `node_modules` sub-directory).

Comment: Ah, Thank you for clearing that up. I had a feeling it was related to OS level interface but I am new to that too so couldn't quite figure it out.

Comment: @shammakh2 - You really should be using `__dirname` to build a path that is relative to your current module.  That is the best practice in a CommonJS module in nodejs.

Comment: Oh, thankyou for informing me. I will do that